# Python - Remove rows from Excel using Pandas based on column part of string

Tags: python, excel, pandas

What i have:
An Excel with 5 thousand of row.
There's 1 colomn that contains an ERROR CGO 20004 string, but the rest of the text can be different in that column for each row.

What i want to do:
Remove that row that contains ERROR CGO 20004 string in that column.

This is my Python code:

```
import pandas as pd

data_frame = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\208825\python\verslag.xlsx')
print(data_frame.head(10))

remove01 = '2022-01-21 10:43:09'

filtered_dataframe = data_frame[data_frame['Ingestuurd'] != remove01]
print(filtered_dataframe.head(10))
```

My problem:
Print shows that the row is removed. This code almost works but remove01 has to be the exact match. Because the column string (the data_frame['Ingestuurd'] is exactly that. So the row is removed.
I want the match to be a part of that string.

So if remove01 would be:

```
remove01 = '-01-21 10:43'
```

I stil need the row to be removed. Can't seem to figure out how to make it work with a match on a part of a string.

Comment: Use the pandas "Isin" method. It works with both dataframes and series

Comment: `data_frame[~data_frame['Ingestuurd'].str.contains(remove01)]`

Comment: @mozway Exception has occurred: AttributeError Can only use .str accessor with string values!

Comment: Any ideas how to solve this one?

Comment: `data_frame[~data_frame['Ingestuurd'].astype(str).str.contains(remove01)]`

Comment: @mozway That was the one. Thanks a lot!